# Running a Python Scheduler every Monday?

Tags: python, scheduler

I am running a scheduler every Monday at 10:00 AM. Here is the code:

```
import schedule
import time

schedule.every().monday.at("10:00").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

My question here is should the value for the time.sleep() be 7days = 604800 seconds or keep it for 1 second?
Can someone please provide a good example and reason how the time.sleep() affects the execution of the program and in this case which way is better: sleep for 1 second or 604800 seconds. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are already using cron, why the schedule module? Just run the job.

Comment: Actually it is not a cron job, it's just a scheduler that will be running every monday based on the script that I've given. I think you misunderstood it because I wrote cron job instead of scheduler

Comment: If it is a matter of life or death and you absolutely have to use the schedule package for scheduling instead of using the os-provided solution, then according to https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ time.sleep(1) should do it. The idea is to periodically check what job needs to be launched and therefore you need to wake up every second.

Comment: @Christophe Thank you for your answer. Is it efficient to wake up every second ? You also mentioned the os-provided solution what is it exactly ? Do you have a documentation or can you please explain more ?

Comment: For Linux you have [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux), for windows you have [scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) @AboudiShukor

Comment: This is how the "schedule" is designed. There is no other way, and therefore no better way, than waking up every second in that context. I would recommend using https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron for scheduling jobs if you are running on linux for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`schedule.run_pending()` simply runs all of the jobs that are due, serially in a loop. The loop with a sleep decides how often the jobs are to be checked, defining a minimum granularity for when jobs are run.

Polling every second is impolite. Unless a CPU is idle anyway, each poll interrupts some other tasks, flushes out memory caches and generally increases the entropy of the universe. You could set a different granularity by changing the sleep. In this example jobs are checked every 10 minutes. So maybe it runs as 10:10 instead of 10:00. That's probably fine and you have interrupted the system 600 fewer times. Polling every hour may be reasonable for your task also.

```
JOB_GRANULARITY_SECONDS = 60 * 10

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(JOB_GRANULARITY_SECONDS)
```

But when there is a significant gap between jobs, why not just figure out the exact time to sleep? You can get the time of the next job and sleep that amount (maybe with a fudge factor to deal with minor fluctuations like the granularity of the clock and the time protocol tossing in a bit of extra time). This example has a 2 second granularity for fudging.

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    next_run_delta = (schedule.next_run - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds()
    if next_run_delta <= 0:
        continue
    time.sleep(next_run_delta + 2)
```

You could also add exception handling for when everything blows up on you

```
while True:
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
    except Exception as e:
        my_alert_fctn(f"Scheduler failed, {e}") # email maybe?
    next_run_delta = (schedule.next_run - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds()
    if next_run_delta < 0:
        continue
    time.sleep(next_run_delta + 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in your opinion the best way to do it if you have big gaps between two jobs is to use the second code you've written right ?

Comment: @AboudiShukor - Yes. In fact, I'd be hard pressed to find a case where polling is better.

Comment: Thank you. I just have one question regarding schedule.next_run. Can you please give me an example how it works ? Like what will it return and based on what is it returning this datetime object ?

Comment: Is it taking the value based on the day that I used in the scheduler in this case Monday or what exactly ?

Comment: Yes, `schedule` converts the next scheduled time for your job into an absolute `datetime.datetime` object and recalculates that time whenever the job is run. We figure out the relative time to the next job by subtracting the current time, and then wait that long. Now when we run the jobs, their datetimes are recalculated and we get a new `next_run` to wait for.